# Confusion about Permutations and Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am going to post two questions here.

Question 1:
A child wants to draw a picture using only three different colors from a set containing twelve different color pencils. In how many ways can the colors be chosen?

Answer = 12C3

Question 2:
In the front of a building there are three doors each to be painted a different colour from twelve different available colours. How many color arrangements for the doors are there?

Answer = 12P3

Now I don't understand what is the difference between the two questions. Both ask for 3 colors to be chosen from 12 colors. Why does order matter in the second one?

If anyone can please clear this confusion, I shall be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order I use different colors to draw a picture doesn't matter - the grass is still green and the sky is still blue when I'm done

The order of the colors of the doors does matter - when the leftmost one is green, the middle one is blue, and the rightmost one is red, that is different from when the leftmost one is red, the middle one is green, and the rightmost one is blue.

Comment: got it thanks mate. nice explanation :)